# Android Nougat not keeping foreground service notification at top

Tags: android, notifications

**Updated** - Found out the root cause of this issue. We are showing the normal notifications as Heads up notifications as follows:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
  notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[0]);
}
```

Whereas the foreground service notification is not Heads up, because it builds the notification every 30 seconds and we don't want that behaviour. If I remove the code for setting up the Heads up notification for normal notifications, then it works fine.

**Original Question:**

Our app has a foreground service for displaying the ongoing score updates for a cricket match via an ongoing `notification`. In every 30 seconds we hit the server API and update the `notification`. We are building this notification with highest priority 2.

Now whenever another normal `notification` of same priority comes, then the normal notification comes on top of the foreground service notification. But since we are building the foreground notification after every 30 seconds, it again comes on top.

This works fine on Marshmallow and below OS. But on Nougat and above, once a new notification comes, the foreground service notification never comes on top. This is the code I have written for building the notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_notification_icon);
builder.setContentIntent(targetIntent);
builder.setDeleteIntent(dismissedIntent);
builder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews);
builder.setContent(remoteViews);
builder.setPriority(2);
Notification notification = builder.build();
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Did anyone face a similar issue? How to keep the foreground service notification always on top on Nougat and above OS.

There is one app [Universal Music App](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/) in which notifications always remains on top. They come down for a moment when a new notification comes, but then again moves back to top.

Comment: Most likely, what you want is not possible. After all, if you and another developer both try to do the same thing, by definition, you cannot both be at the top. Probably Google changed Android to stop developers from spamming the top spot.

Comment: but the thing is that various Music apps like Universal Music App are able to  be on top. They come down for a moment when a new notification comes, but then again moves back to top.

Comment: At least on Android 8.0, I know that Google is setting the order based on content, with media players at the top.

Comment: Can you provide a link which says so? Will be helpful

Comment: This was covered at Google I|O; I do not know if it is documented anywhere.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Find out the root cause of this issue. We are setting our other notifications as Heads up notification. If I don't set other notifications as heads up, then its works fine.